# How to enable SSL with a IIS 6 + FastCGI + Django setup?

Tags: python, django, iis, ssl, fastcgi

I have successfully setup FastCGI/Django on a IIS 6 Server.

What I don't know how to do, is to enable SSL connections.

---

**Any tips or ideas to get me started?** I'm not an IIS expert, so this is quite confusing for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an IIS expert either, although I do have my own web server.

Have you installed your SSL certificate?  If so try reading,

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5055536.html

which should assist you in completing the installation.