# How to configure HTTPS for Django server on IIS 10

Tags: django, https, ssl-certificate, iis-10

My client is developed using Vue and server using Django. We've hosted this on IIS 10. As for the SSL certificate we got from GoDaddy. I was successfully able to configure to the client. However when I run the app, I'm getting the following error.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxx.yyy.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/yyyy/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

What I understand is that we need to configure the Django server to allow HTTPS. I need assistance on how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

The error has said everything about the issue. While the Vue on client has configured certificate and can use https, the Django on server still use http. So you need to configure Django to enable https connection.

Install the certificate on server, I'm not sure the certificate you got is only suit for client or server. You can consult the certificate provider.

When you deploy the Django on IIS, select https and the certificate when adding the website.
[image]

Then in SSL setting module, check the Require SSL and Require.
[image]

I'm not an expert on Django, so all these settings are related to https on IIS. Regard to enable https on Django, you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013536/how-to-enable-ssl-with-a-iis-6-fastcgi-django-setup).

Comment: Thanks. Let me check if I can use the same SSL certificate for both Vue and Django.